# iOS Location Services do not run after terminating app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, location

First time posting here, so please forgive me if I'm asking a question with a simple answer, but I can't seem to find anything relevant for my case.

I'm trying to have location services run on an iOS app indefinitely throughout pretty much all the stages of the app lifecycle. The user has an option inside the app to activate a certain functionality which starts location services, with the expectation that these services must run even while the app is terminated.

The issue I'm having here is that, when I terminate the app manually, it just stops working.

Here's what I've done so far:

> 1. Added background modes in Capabilities (`location`)
> 2. Added `Application does not run in background mode` and set it to `NO` in Info.plist. Also added the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and
>      `NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription`.
> 3. When initializing `CLLocationManager`, I have set the following: `desiredAccuracy` to `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`;
>      `distanceFilter` to `kCLDistanceFilterNone`; `activityType` to
>      `CLActivityTypeFitness`; `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `NO`;
>      `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to `YES`; and calling
>      `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.
> 4. Tried initiating significant or region monitoring on `applicationWillTerminate:` method in the app delegate.

So, I understand that what I've done in point 4 should restart the app once a change is detected. At least I've managed to get that much to work with significant changes but not with region monitoring. However, it does not work instantly. The only way I found this to work instantly is to either deactivate/activate airplane mode, or turn the device off and on.

Is there any way to make this work (almost) instantly after terminating the app? What I want to achieve here is to relaunch the app right after the user has terminated it, so that the app can continue to do whatever it needs to do with location services. Would there be any implications when submitting to the app store?

I have seen some things about using a background task to achieve this, could this be the way to go?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I terminate the app manually, it just stops working"? Terminating means to remove it out of memory and background.

Comment: The app is closed, just as you say. The app is not in memory nor in background. I guess it is to be expected that location services will stop when this is done, but as far as I can tell it is possible to relaunch the app even after terminating the app.

Comment: no its not possible. once the app is flicked out of memory it cannot relaunch itself unless user clicks on it. If its not in the background it cannot do anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But if I use significant changes, for instance, the app can be reopened, not by itself, but by another process (I think it's locationd). I have tested closing the app and then after moving the device by 500 meters (or closely around that), there's activity from the app in the console log (I added calls to NSLog in didUpdateLocations to verify this). I could be seeing this wrong :-), but thats what I'm getting.

Comment: Apple docs also seem to suggest this behaviour: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html , under "Using Location Services in the Background" section. Maybe using region monitoring would be the way to go for this, I'm just not sure how to go about this and how reliable it would be.

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is not guaranteed to be called. If the user terminates your app is is almost certain that this method will not be called.

Comment: I have changed the call to start monitoring for significant changes to `applicationDidEnterBackground`, but the result appears to be the same. However, it probably makes more sense to be there instead of `applicationWillTerminate` anyway (maybe even consider putting this when the location services are first started),